# Where can I see an example of client prediction in a multiplayer game written in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, client, prediction

There is surprisingly little out there except abstract theory. I have found Gabriel Gambetta's abstract discussion about it on https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-side-prediction-server-reconciliation.html. But I have not yet been able to find real code where client prediction has been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The last page of Gabriel's article contains a live demo. If you view the source of the page you can see the code.

view-source:https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-side-prediction-live-demo.html